# Segmentation fault instead of constructor call

Tags: c++, constructor

I'm trying to a bit modified of built-in allocation function:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <new>

struct A
{
    int a;
    A(){ std::cout << "Constructor\n"; a = 3; }
    void* operator new(std::size_t t) noexcept
    {
        ::operator new(t);
        return NULL;
    }
};

int main()
{
    new A();
}
```

[demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2f3ed02749b8aaa7)

Instead of constructor call I've got `segmentation fault`. Could you explain that behavior?

Comment: BTW, if you don't want your `operator new` to leak exceptions, use `::operator new(t, std::nothrow)`

Comment: (Otherwise a failed allocation will call `std::terminate` with no opportunity for the calling code to recover)

Comment: @Brian Thanks for mentioning that; I have edited my answer to accommodate for your recommendation.

Comment: This question is a lot more interesting than it looks.  Returning a null pointer from `operator new()` has to be legal, because the `nothrow` version does.  And then the *new-expression* should evaluate to a null pointer without calling any constructor at all.

Comment: @BenVoigt I never thought of it in that way. The big question is: why is this considered 'legal'? Maybe because the code created a duplicate of `t`?

Comment: On what compiler do you see this behavior?

Comment: I get a segfault in gcc 4.9.0, but not in gcc 4.8.2. I'll look for a bug report.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a bug, because the call to `::operator new()` could throw `std::bad_alloc`, violating the exception-specification of your class-specific allocator (zybox's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24854043/103167) shows how to fix this).  However, that's very unlikely to happen in such a small program.  It's also a bad idea to override `operator new()` without also providing `operator delete()`, although I can't find an explicit requirement that both must be found in the same scope.

Returning a null pointer from your allocator is both legal and the correct way to indicate an allocation failure.  In 3.7.4.1, the Standard says that:

> An  allocation  function  that  fails  to  allocate  storage  can  invoke  the  currently  installed  new-handler  function (18.6.2.3), if any.  [ Note:  A program-supplied allocation function can obtain the address of the currently installed `new_handler` using the `std::get_new_handler` function (18.6.2.4).  — end note ] If an allocation function declared with a non-throwing *exception-specification* (15.4) fails to allocate storage, it shall return a null pointer. Any other allocation function that fails to allocate storage shall indicate failure only by throwing an exception (15.1) of a type that would match a handler (15.3) of type std::bad_alloc (18.6.2.1).

Then in 5.3.4:

> If the allocation function returns null, initialization shall not be done, the deallocation function shall not be called, and the value of the new-expression shall be null.

The code is legal on the path that `::operator new()` doesn't throw -- the expression `new A()` in `main()` evaluates to a null pointer, which is ok because it never gets dereferenced.

You shouldn't get a constructor call either.  What you should get is a memory leak, since there is no `::operator delete()` call corresponding to the `::operator new(t)` inside your allocator.

Comment: I hope there's a comment coming explaining the downvote; I'm quite interested if someone has a Standard citation making member `operator new` without `operator delete` undefined behavior.

Comment: Even more interesting is operator delete without operator new!

Comment: N37979 5.3.4/21 appears to cover the case of `T::operator new` existing without `T::operator delete`

Comment: It seems a bit fishy that `new T` can return a null pointer sometimes

Comment: @Ben Voigt You did not point out the reason of the segmentation fault.

Comment: @zyboxinternational: I didn't downvote yours.  I downvoted Vlad's because the only explanation it contained was factually incorrect.  The constructor does not write anything, because it doesn't run.

Comment: @BenVoigt Oh, ok. Reading your own comment on your answer, it seems that someone has downvoted our answers without commenting/explaining why. I've always disliked users who do that..

Comment: @MattMcNabb: It does definitely describe the search order for the deallocation function.  I would have preferred a rule that looks in the same scope as the allocation function, but then again, the number of placement parameters (and therefore which allocation overload is selected) isn't available at deallocation.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow: There is no segmentation fault on a conforming implementation.  The only failure mode allowed by the language specification is a call to `std::terminate`, if the global allocation function failed and threw `std::bad_alloc`.  Otherwise, the code should run without error.

Comment: That is, I don't have a _Segmentation fault_ in a normal way. My allocator must return null-pointer. And there is memory leaking. Do I understand you correctly?

Comment: In any way your answer has clarified some allocation concepts. Thanks.

Comment: @DmitryFucintv: Normally you do not want an allocation function to return null, because then the object can't be created.  But sometimes it happens.  Maybe you are using a pool allocator to reduce fragmentation, and the pool of 1000 objects are all in use.  Well then your allocator fails, and returning null is one of the two ways to indicate that (the other is throwing `std::bad_alloc` exception)

Answer (score 1):

Your function operator `new` contains a `null` pointer, and as such doesn't actually return anything.

The `null` function operator is equal to `return false;`, or just `return;`, but be warned: duplicating a pointer using the `new` operator causes memory leaks if you aren't careful. To get around this, just `delete(t)` when you're done.

The following code will fix your issue:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <new>

struct A
{
    int a;
    A(){ std::cout << "Constructor\n"; a = 3; }
    void* operator new(std::size_t t) noexcept
    {
        return ::operator new(t, std::nothrow);
    }
};

int main()
{
    new A();
}
```

Comment: Your text doesn't make any sense; the function returns a null pointer (which is a thing). It is not equivalent to `return;` which would be illegal here. Further, OP is asking about what is supposed to happen when `operator new` does return NULL.  Suggesting he stop returning NULL does not address the question.

Answer (score 0):

The original code simply returns `NULL` from `A::operator new`, quietly forgetting the return result of `::operator new` (a memory leak). The reason for the crash is that the pointer returned is then used as the `this` pointer for the new `A` object. Since that pointer is `NULL`, anything the constructor does with the object (assigning `a = 3`) is dereferencing `NULL`. That results in a segmentation violation. zyboxinternational's answer above gives a good solution, and the comments of both previous posters are very relevant.

Comment: "the pointer returned is then used as the `this` pointer for the new `A` object"  Not when it is null.  When the pointer returned is null, it becomes the result of the *new-expression* (`new A()`) without any constructor executing.